# Как сделать проверку на наличие логина в Telegram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telebot

я решил сделать так, чтобы люди без логина не могли пользоваться ботом(тк это ломало его), и я попробовал следующий код

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handler_start(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    login = message.from_user.username
    print(login)
    print(login == "None")
    if "None" == login:
        bot.send_message(chat_id,'Для продолжения работы с ботом, вам необходимо установить логин!')
    else:
        Что-то происходит
```

Как оказалось, на сравнение None и None(именно так бот определяет логин людей у которых его нет) неверным выражением(False). Почему так, и что нужно сделать?

Comment: Потому что `None` и `"None"` это совершенно разные вещи

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ты пробовал написать None без кавычек ???